# Protractor typescript finding first element from list of elements

Tags: typescript, protractor

Here I am trying to locate it by using xpath as .//div[@class="pq-select-menu"]//span[contains(text(), "filecaseone")]/parent::label/input
 and code snippet is as following

```html
<div class="pq-select-popup ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width: 300px;">
<label class="pq-select-all ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close "></span>
<input type="checkbox">Select All</label>
<div class="pq-select-search-div ui-corner-all">
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-search "></span>
<div class="pq-select-search-div1">
<input type="text" class="pq-select-search-input" autocomplete="off"></div></div>
<div class="pq-select-menu">
<label class="pq-select-option-label ui-state-enable" id="pq-option-528-0">
<input type="checkbox"><span class="pq-left-input">abc1203</span></label>
<label class="pq-select-option-label ui-state-enable" id="pq-option-528-1">
<input type="checkbox"><span class="pq-left-input">abc123</span></label>
<label class="pq-select-option-label ui-state-enable" id="pq-option-528-2">
<input type="checkbox"><span class="pq-left-input">CRdemoCase</span></label>
<label class="pq-select-option-label ui-state-enable" id="pq-option-528-3">
<input type="checkbox"><span class="pq-left-input">exportCase</span></label>
<label class="pq-select-option-label ui-state-enable" id="pq-option-528-4">
<input type="checkbox"><span class="pq-left-input">hdfhdfhdfdfgdfgdfgd</span></label>
<label class="pq-select-option-label ui-state-enable" id="pq-option-528-5">
<input type="checkbox"><span class="pq-left-input">Quinccasenewone1002</span></label>
<label class="pq-select-option-label ui-state-enable" id="pq-option-528-6">
<input type="checkbox"><span class="pq-left-input">Quinccasenewone1003</span></label>
<label class="pq-select-option-label ui-state-enable" id="pq-option-528-7">
<input type="checkbox"><span class="pq-left-input">Quinccasenewone1004</span>
</label><label class="pq-select-option-label ui-state-enable pq-state-hover" id="pq-option-528-8">
<input type="checkbox"><span class="pq-left-input">Quinccasenewone1006</span></label>
<label class="pq-select-option-label ui-state-enable" id="pq-option-528-9">
<input type="checkbox"><span class="pq-left-input">Quinccasenewone1007</span></label>
<label class="pq-select-option-label ui-state-enable" id="pq-option-528-10">
<input type="checkbox"><span class="pq-left-input">Quinccasenewone1100</span></label>
<label class="pq-select-option-label ui-state-enable" id="pq-option-528-11">
<input type="checkbox"><span class="pq-left-input">Quinccasenewone1101</span></label>
<label class="pq-select-option-label ui-state-enable" id="pq-option-528-12"><input type="checkbox"><span class="pq-left-input">testCase</span></label></div></div>
```

In typescript protractor I am finding multiple elements with same label ,how i can find first one

I tried loop as well as .first

```
let inputEle = element.all(by.xpath('.//div[@class="pq-select-menu"]//span[contains(text(), "filecaseone")]/parent::label/input'));
for (i=0; i < inputEle.count; i++){
  valueInList= await inputEle.[0].isSelected());
}

element.all(locator).first()

let val=await inputEle.first().isSelected();
```

Comment: What issue you are getting? Above both approach is correct

Comment: Now getting "ElementNotVisibleError: element not interactable" error I also added static wait but it does't work.

Comment: Check xpath if it located correctly, If yes then there must be need to add wait for Element visible

Comment: @sadikAli yes xpath is correct and there are too many elements i am using chai libarary but it does't work for me.    I am writing code as for wait                                     var expected = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    var el = element.all(by.xpath('//div[@class="pq-select-menu"]//span[contains(text(), "abc123")]'));
    await browser.wait(expected.visibilityOf(el.first()));
    await el.first().click();

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
const list = element.all(by.css('span.pq-left-input'));

await ele.get(0);
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks @Madhan I am getting error element is not interactable in typescript I tried to add wait as well as expected condition but still getting same error can you tell what can be the issue.

Comment: @IhsanRehman To confirm you are trying to select the option from drop-down? If yes, Try the updated answer.